# The traffic is not routed correctly after the network interface on worker node is restarted

Tags: kubernetes, iptables

We have a statefulset with 2 replicas, on each pod there is Postgres instance. One acts as master while the other acts as replica.

There are 2 services exposed, one is PG master service and the other is PG replica service. Both services are without selector, and there are 2 endpoints sharing the name of its related service.

The IP of the Postgres pod will be patched into endpoints so that the traffic can be routed to the correct pod when accessing the service.

For example, PG master service is corresponding to the endpoint of the same name, and in that endpoint there is ip of the pod running master Postgres instance.

There is another traffic pod which will set up the DB connection to the master Postgres service.

The problem is:

1.The traffic pod(issue DB connections with JDBC) and PG master pod are in the same worker node(let’s call it worker1).

2.The PG replica pod is in another worker(worker2).

3.Run a testing case which is: “Shutdown network interface on worker1, sleep 60s, take up network interface on worker1”

4.Then the previous PG replica pod is promoted to master, and the previous PG master pod is demoted to replica.

5.The traffic pod’s target address is the PG master service name but at that time it connects to the replica pod. Thus the traffic could try to write to a PG in ‘read-only’ mode and test case fails.

The kube-proxy mode is iptables.
We suspect the iptables in kube-proxy doesn’t update the routing information in time. It means the iptables could update the routing information a bit later than the traffic pod establishing the DB connection.

We made a restart of the kube-proxy and the problem hasn't been reproduced since then. That's strange.
So we hope to know the root cause of that but haven't got clue.

Here is the kubectl version:

```
•Kubernetes version (use kubectl version):
 Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"19", GitVersion:"v1.19.3", GitCommit:"1e11e4a2108024935ecfcb2912226cedeafd99df", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-10-14T12:50:19Z", GoVersion:"go1.15.2", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
 Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"19", GitVersion:"v1.19.3", GitCommit:"91fb1371fc570cfd3b3052012ce68fdd78b41c07", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-10-28T08:47:48Z", GoVersion:"go1.15.2", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes? This is just a thing that happens, there is no way to atomically update things because the world is not transactional. Any active-passive HA system doing this kind of failover will have a time in which the system is not converged. The important thing is that Postgres itself never have more than one primary. It can have fewer than one, but never more. It sounds like you have that working, the demoted replica would be in read-only mode and any write queries sent to it would get an error as they should.

Comment: I think for educational purposes would be nice to mention, that pods are run by `kubelet`, whereas changes to `iptables` are done via `kube-proxy` and there is no synchronization mechanism between those 2 components.

Comment: There is synchronization it's just not globally transactional and takes time. Both of those are just realities of physics. Both components sync and otherwise communicate via kube-apiserver, that's kind of the whole point of Kubernetes :)

Comment: Yes, maybe I expressed myself in a wrong way. There is a non-explicit sync., of course, since the API server is the only place where those components get information to act upon. Ad you said - it's not supposed to be atomic, and it wouldn't make sense to attempt to make it atomic. The problem is that not all people understand this interaction flow - that's why I suggested you to dig a little to the internals of k8s in your answer and explain why it happens. I should have said "there is no explicit synchronization mechanism between those two". Anyway, feel free to ignore my comment :)